# How to style whenever virtual keyboard appears?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am creating a ReactJs app and was testing it on a tablet. So whenever the virtual keyboard pops out the divs and other Html elements like input shrinks. Since I am using viewport height for dynamic styling, I understand if the screen is shrinking the size of Html element has to shrink. But the issue here is I cannot but not use 'vh' or '%', given I want my app to look good in different resolution screens.